# MongoDB не сохраняет данные при остановке контейнера с volume

Tags: docker, mongodb

Не понимаю в чём проблема, при остановке докер контейнера MongoDB не сохраняет данные. Потом я заново с помощью команды `docker-compose up` включаю контейнеры и БД снова пустая.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always

        environment:
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
          MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: users
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - mongo

        ports:
          - 8081:8081

        environment:
          ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
          ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
          ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
  
    myapplication:
        image: application
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - mongo
          - mongo-express

        ports:
          - 8080:8080

        environment:
          MONGODB_CONNSTRING: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
EXPOSE 8080:8080
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./build/install/example/ /app/
WORKDIR /app/bin
CMD ["./example"]
```

Comment: а почему вы решили что он "c volume", в docker compose вы volume не используете?

Comment: да,прошу прощения за ошибку,правда я так и не разобрался как правильно его написать

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы у вас данные сохранялись можно использовать `volume`. Есть два способа, первый позволяет вам примонтировать папку с вашей системы (хоста) в контейнера, например, в папку `data`, которая лежит рядом с `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: users
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
...
```

Или при помощи `volume`:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: users
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db

...
  
volumes: 
  mongo-data:
```

Comment: то есть в самом проекте всегда должна быть папка с моей бд, правильно?Просто непонимаю что именно я должен положить в volumes:... путь к моей бд локально?Подскажите пожалуйста, просто не могу понять что именно нужно указать в volume в моем случае

Comment: @SergeyTretyakov, нужно указывать путь где вы хотите хранить данные, обычно для тестов, указывают на папку в проекте, но не обязательно чтобы там что-то было, mongo при первом запуске создаст все что нужно, а дальше уже будет переиспользовать